# Pandas DataFrame: Can't iterate over Grouped Series

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So I have the following Panda Series `grouped`:

```
                               Amount
Ticker Unit   Date       Time        
FLWS   SHARES 2019-01-03 -       20.0
              2019-01-13 -       20.0
PIH    SHARES 2019-01-13 -      -10.0
       VALUE  2019-01-03 -      -25.0
```

*I wanted to reset the index to remove the 'Amount' as a multi-index and "drop-it-down" but then the grouping becomes unstacked and this only after the Series is converted to a DataFrame.

I am trying to iterate over the groups:

```
    for ticker, action, date, time in grouped:
        print(ticker)
        print(action)
        print(date)
        print(time)
```

but I get the following: `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

ADDITIONAL INFO:
I get the mentioned dataframe from the following:

```
orders = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([
        ('Ticker', tickers),
        ('Action', actions),
        ('Unit', units),
        ('Amount', amounts),
        ('Date', dates),
        ('Time', times),
    ]))

    df_orders = pd.DataFrame(orders)
if not df_orders.empty:
    df_orders.loc[df_orders['Action'] == 'SELL', 'Amount'] *= -1
    grouped = df_orders.groupby(['Ticker', 'Unit', 'Date', 'Time'])['Amount'].apply(np.sum) 

    print(grouped)
```

where `tickers`, `actions`, `units`, etc are all lists

EDIT: 
I figured it would be best to show the logic in which I wanted to handle the acquired data.

```
total = 0
for ticker in tickers: 
    for date in dates:    
        if unit=='SHARES':
            total += some_function(ticker, date)
        else:
            total += some_function(ticker, date)
```

notice in this case, every ticker in tickers would be unique. So how would you iterate over the grouped series in this manner?

Comment: What do you expect `for ticker, action, date, time in grouped:` to return? Why not just iterate over the original data frame?

Comment: Are you referring to the pre-grouped `df`? Because I only want to iterate over unique entries i.e. there might be multiple entries with the same `ticker`, etc. How would you suggest proceeding given that ?

Comment: How do you define *unique entries*? As far as I understood the multi-index `ticker, action, date, time` *is* unique.

Comment: @a_guest Unique in the sense that there will be only one ticker of its kind available and by referencing that ticker, subsequent data (action, date, time) would be extracted accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that by just iterating over `grouped` itself, you iterate over the values in the Series which are just the values in the `Amount` column. Note also that `ticker`, `action`, `date`, and `time` are the indices of the Series, not its values. Thus you are trying to assign `ticker, action, date, time` to a single float. Hence the error `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. In Python 3 the error is a bit more helpful as `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object`.

To fix this, you should use the `iteritems` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html)) method of the Pandas Series class. This iterates over each item in the Series and returns the index and value as a tuple on each iteration. Since you have a compound index, that index will also be a tuple, which you can unpack into different values with something like this:

```
for (ticker, action, date, time), amount in grouped.iteritems():
    print(ticker)
    print(action)
    print(date)
    print(time)
```

**Edit:** [Addressing the edit to the question.]

In the code sample you provide, the tickers are, in some sense, unique, however you call `some_function` on the same ticker potentially multiple times, so the tickers don't actually need to be unique. Perhaps what you can do is something like this:

```
grouped = df_orders.groupby(['ticker', 'date', 'unit'])['amount'].agg(sum)

total = 0
for (ticker, date, unit), amount in grouped.iteritems():
    if unit == 'SHARES':
        total += share_function(ticker, date)
    else:
        total += other_function(ticker, date)
```

Comment: So I notice that in iterating over the Series, still multiple entries with the same ticker appear. I guess the idea end result eliminates this - I will clarify in question

Comment: @SterlingButters you're grouping by ticker, action, date, *and* time so it's entirely possible for there to be two rows with the same ticker if, for example, they have different dates. This is an issue with the `groupby` rather than the iteration. If you want no duplicate tickers, then you'll need to group by ticker alone

Comment: Please see my edit. Maybe my initial question/logic was misleading but I hope that you will be able to deduce what I seek from my edit

Comment: @SterlingButters added an edit to my answer, let me know if that helps